# How to run shell file as entrypoint when using docker image with tomcat:9.0.45-jdk8-adoptopenjdk-hotspot in a dockerfile?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am creating a docker file using docker image tomcat:9.0.45-jdk8-adoptopenjdk-hotspot. To run the dockerfile I use the command `docker run -it -p 8888:8080 tomcatcustom` , this turns on the tomcat server.

I would like to run another custom .sh file along with tomcat server that gets executed with running the docker image. How could I define the Entrypoint in the dockerfile that I have created so that I can have both the tomcat as well as my .sh file executed ?

or is there any other option?

Answer (score 0):

The `Dockerfile` can only have one Entrypoint that is executed, but nothing stops you from having a script as entrypoint that runs your custom script and tomcat.
E.g.

if you have a directory with

```
Dockerfile
custom.sh // your custom script
start.sh
```

where `start.sh` is

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
./custom.sh &
catalina.sh run
```

and `Dockerfile` is

```
FROM tomcat:9.0.45-jdk8-adoptopenjdk-hotspot
COPY start.sh .
COPY custom.sh .
CMD "./start.sh"
```

In that case `custom.sh` is executed in the background (with `&`) so that tomcat is started in parallel.